# Rails: rake db:migrate suddenly starts at version 0 again, should start at version 16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

today I just ran rake db:migrate... well, two things happened, first it reversed from version 2 to 0, so it smashed my user db (very very annoying) and now it wants to migrate vom version 1. But it should start at version 16.

Any Ideas?
Shema.rb is okay and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok that was simple... by some reasons shema_info in the databse was corrupted... i have absolutely no idea why...

Comment: you mean the "schema_migrations" table right? Just making sure we're thinking of the same table. Perhaps that name is configurable? Not sure on that.